# Creating an application that can be controlled externally via GetObject call

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program in VS 2012 (VB) that I can then access via other programs (including Excel's vba) using GetObject or CreateObject. I would like to be able to declare a variable in the client program and assign it a class object from the server program. I have successfully create dlls that I can access (using comClass and registering) but doing this with an exe is eluding me. I have tried creating a comClass and registering it via /REGSERVER but when I try to use GetOBject I get an error saying that it cannot create an ActiveX component. Could anyone enlighten me?
THanks

Answer (score 1):

Kindly follow given Steps
Step 1 : Convert Extension XYS.EXE to XYZ.DLL
Step 2 : Import This DLL to your new Project.
Step 3 : then
 Dim Obj As Object = New Test.Form1()
            Obj.show()

For an Example :
Create Project Nameed "Test"
Compile Project 
Now we get Test.Exe
Change Extension EXE to DLL=> Test.DLL

Now Create Another Project Nameed "Test2"
Import "Test.dll"
Add Button in new project
On Button Click Event put Given Code
   Dim Obj As Object = New Test.Form1()
   Obj.show()

It Works for Me

Comment: Your suggestion does indeed work as you mention, however, it doesn't really provide any improvement on just creating the original server application as a dll in the first place. The reason an exe is being used is that more than one application will try to access the same instance of it. I want multiple applications being able to read the same exe object rather than instantiate a new object each time a client application is created.